# Сократить код обращения к одинаковым свойствам классов, когда они реализованы разными базовыми классами/интерфейсами?

Tags: c#, unity3d, ооп, инспекция-кода, шаблоны-проектирования

Пишу простой tweener на Unity. Движок предоставляет классы (компоненты) для рендера, и у тех, что я использую есть свойство **color**, но эти классы не наследуются от чего то, что имеет это свойство и не реализуют единого интерфейса, что обязывал бы реализовывать свойство цвета. В итоге мне приходиться писать повторяющийся код:

```
            foreach (var mesh in texts)
            {
                Color delta = (endColor - mesh.color) / frames;

                for (int i = 0; i < frames; i++)
                {
                    mesh.color += delta;

                    yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
                }
            }

            foreach (var mesh in images)
            {
                Color delta = (endColor - mesh.color) / frames;

                for (int i = 0; i < frames; i++)
                {
                    mesh.color += delta;

                    yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
                }
            }

            foreach (var mesh in sprites)
            {
                Color delta = (endColor - mesh.color) / frames;

                for (int i = 0; i < frames; i++)
                {
                    mesh.color += delta;

                    yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
                }
            }
```

Казалось бы, очевидным решением было бы использовать **dynamic** тип, но как известно Microsoft немного накосячили и у нас в .Net Framework **4.0** кривой RuntimeBinder и использовать dynamic тип я не могу (так-то могу, но это затратно по ресурсам и времени написания и вообще это всё были бы костыли). Так же не хочу использовать явное приведение внутри цикла, так как это более нечитаемый код и менее эффективно по ресурсам, хоть и ненамного.

Так как же всё таки сократить это?

Полный код функции:

```
public static GameObject Paint(this GameObject obj, Color endColor, int frames, float wait = float.NaN)
    {
        IEnumerator AwaitPaint()
        {
            var texts = new List<TextMesh>();
            var images = new List<Image>();
            var sprites = new List<SpriteRenderer>();

            void AddComponents()
            {
                var childrens = new List<GameObject>();

                void AddChildrens(GameObject _obj)
                {
                    var newChildrens = new List<GameObject>();

                    foreach (Transform tr in _obj.transform)
                    {
                        childrens.Add(tr.gameObject); 
                        newChildrens.Add(tr.gameObject);
                    }

                    foreach (GameObject __obj in newChildrens.ToArray())
                    {
                        AddChildrens(__obj);
                    }
                }

                AddChildrens(obj);

                foreach (var text in obj.GetComponents<TextMesh>())
                {
                    texts.Add(text);
                }
                foreach (var image in obj.GetComponents<Image>())
                {
                    images.Add(image);
                }
                foreach (var sprite in obj.GetComponents<SpriteRenderer>())
                {
                    sprites.Add(sprite);
                }
            }

            AddComponents();

            if (!float.IsNaN(wait))
            {
                yield return new WaitForSeconds(wait);
            }

            foreach (var mesh in texts)
            {
                Color delta = (endColor - (Color)mesh.color) / frames;

                for (int i = 0; i < frames; i++)
                {
                    mesh.color += delta;

                    yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
                }
            }

            foreach (var mesh in images)
            {
                Color delta = (endColor - (Color)mesh.color) / frames;

                for (int i = 0; i < frames; i++)
                {
                    mesh.color += delta;

                    yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
                }
            }

            foreach (var mesh in sprites)
            {
                Color delta = (endColor - (Color)mesh.color) / frames;

                for (int i = 0; i < frames; i++)
                {
                    mesh.color += delta;

                    yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
                }
            }

            called.Remove(called.Same(obj));
        }

        if (called.FindIndex((x) => x.obj == obj) >= 0)
        {
            CoroutineContainer.Stop(called.Same(obj).coroutine);
            called.Remove(called.Same(obj));
        }

        called.Add((obj, CoroutineContainer.Start(AwaitPaint())));

        return obj;
    }
```

Вызов:

```
gameObject.Paint(new Color(1, 1, 1, 1), 30);
```

Comment: А вот эти текста и прочие штуки - что это? Какой тип?

Comment: Что за массивы `texts`, `images` и `sprites`?

Comment: @RiotBr3aker это массивы тех самых компонентов, что предоставляет движок

Comment: Приведите код, как вы: **а)** их получаете и **б)** запускаете твины.

Comment: @RiotBr3aker 
a) public static GameObject Paint(this GameObject obj, Color endColor, int frames, float wait = float.NaN){ // код }
б) gameObject.Paint(new Color(1, 0, 0, 1), 30);

Надеюсь, что это то.

Comment: В вопрос добавьте, не в комментарии

Comment: @RiotBr3aker обновил.

Comment: <p> этот код сократить наврядли получится. </p>
<p> скорее всего нужно менять подход к решению задачи </p>
<p> либо оставить так </p>

Comment: Во-первых, нет, код сократить получится, во-вторых, крутой ответ ;)

Comment: использовать обобщение вместо texts, images и sprites, не?

Comment: Самый очевидный способ использовать ООП, т.е. использовать общий интерфейс или обобщение.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Есть такая замечательная вещь - [паттерн проектирования "Адаптер"](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80_(%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)), который позволяет совместить несовместимое.

Помимо того, что это подход сильно упростит метод, он также позволит поддерживать не только указанные в вопросе компоненты, но в целом любые компоненты, которые так или иначе имеют какой-то изменяемый цвет, написав соответствующий адаптер.

---

Для начала нужно определиться, что нам вообще нужно получить от всех этих объектов:

1. Возможность получить текущий цвет
2. Возможность изменить текущий цвет

Для чего реализуем интерфейс:

```
public interface IColorChanger {
    void ChangeColor(Color delta);
    Color GetColor();
}
```

Реализуем этот интерфейс для конкретного типа `TextMesh` (все остальное в самом конце):

```
public class TextMeshColorAdapter : IColorChanger {
    private TextMesh _target;

    public TextMeshColorAdapter(TextMesh target) {
        _target = target;
    }

    public void ChangeColor(Color delta) {
        _target.color += delta;
    }

    public Color GetColor() {
        return _target.color;
    }
}
```

---

**Не совсем относится к вопросу, но решил и это исправить**:

Не стоит писать свои велосипеды по рекурсивному поиску всех потомков объекта, метод `GetComponentsInChildren` сделает все сам.

---

Адаптеры разных компонентов можно объединить в один список и вместо кучи циклов сделать парочку LINQ запросов:

```
var targets = new List<IColorChanger>();

targets.AddRange(
    obj.GetComponentsInChildren<TextMesh>().Select(txt => new TextMeshColorAdapter(txt))
);
targets.AddRange(
    obj.GetComponentsInChildren<Image>().Select(img => new ImageColorAdapter(img))
);
targets.AddRange(
    obj.GetComponentsInChildren<SpriteRenderer>().Select(sprite => new SpriteRendererColorAdapter(sprite))
);
```

Благодаря общему интерфейсу также можно один раз пройтись по общему массиву и поменять цвет каждого элемента:

```
foreach (var target in targets) {
    var deltaColor = (endColor - target.GetColor()) / frames;

    for (int i = 0; i < frames; i++)
    {
        target.ChangeColor(deltaColor);

        yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
    }
}
```

---

### Полный код

**Адаптеры**

```
public interface IColorChanger {
    void ChangeColor(Color delta);
    Color GetColor();
}

public class TextMeshColorAdapter : IColorChanger {
    private TextMesh _target;

    public TextMeshColorAdapter(TextMesh target) {
        _target = target;
    }

    public void ChangeColor(Color delta) {
        _target.color += delta;
    }

    public Color GetColor() {
        return _target.color;
    }
}

public class ImageColorAdapter : IColorChanger {
    private Image _target;

    public ImageColorAdapter(Image target) {
        _target = target;
    }

    public void ChangeColor(Color delta) {
        _target.color += delta;
    }

    public Color GetColor() {
        return _target.color;
    }
}

public class SpriteRendererColorAdapter : IColorChanger  {
    private SpriteRenderer _target;

    public SpriteRendererColorAdapter(SpriteRenderer target) {
        _target = target;
    }

    public void ChangeColor(Color delta) {
        _target.color += delta;
    }

    public Color GetColor() {
        return _target.color;
    }
}
```

**Метод**

```
public static GameObject Paint(this GameObject obj, Color endColor, int frames, float wait = float.NaN)
{
    IEnumerator AwaitPaint()
    {
        var targets = new List<IColorChanger>();

        targets.AddRange(obj.GetComponentsInChildren<TextMesh>().Select(txt => new TextMeshColorAdapter(txt)));
        targets.AddRange(obj.GetComponentsInChildren<Image>().Select(img => new ImageColorAdapter(img)));
        targets.AddRange(obj.GetComponentsInChildren<SpriteRenderer>().Select(sprite => new SpriteRendererColorAdapter(sprite)));

        if (!float.IsNaN(wait))
        {
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(wait);
        }

        foreach (var target in targets) {
            var deltaColor = (endColor - target.GetColor()) / frames;

            for (int i = 0; i < frames; i++)
            {
                target.ChangeColor(deltaColor);

                yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
            }
        }

        called.Remove(called.Same(obj));
    }

    if (called.FindIndex((x) => x.obj == obj) >= 0)
    {
        CoroutineContainer.Stop(called.Same(obj).coroutine);
        called.Remove(called.Same(obj));
    }

    called.Add((obj, CoroutineContainer.Start(AwaitPaint())));

    return obj;
}
```

Comment: Да, это то, что нужно. Немного стыдно, что я мог забыть про Адаптер. На счет `GetComponentsInChildren` : я не был в нём уверен, так как думал, что он мог не захватить компоненты с родительского объекта, в итоге решил подстраховаться (хоть и не лучшим образом).

Comment: @NasItaHighborne не стесняйтесь обращаться к документации, там много полезной информации, а насчет "стыдно" - да ладно, все мы когда-нибудь что-то забываем ;)

Answer (score 3):

Можно написать универсальный обработчик типа

```
static public IEnumerator ColorForList<T> (this List<T> list, Color endColor, float frames) {
    foreach (var element in list) {
        Color delta = (endColor-element.GetColor())/frames;
        for (int i = 0; i < frames; i++) {
            element.SetColor(delta);
            yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
        }
    }
}
static Color GetColor<T> (this T someType) { ... }
static Color SetColor<T> (this T someType, Color color) { ... }
```

Чтобы потом просто вызвать

```
StartCoroutine(texts.ColorForList(endColor, frames));
StartCoroutine(images.ColorForList(endColor, frames));
StartCoroutine(sprites.ColorForList(endColor, frames));
```

Comment: на сколько помню. корутины в статике, можно только через `Awake` `instance = this;` вызывать, иначе они отказываются работать...

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но, как выясняется, без явного приведения здесь не обойтись, так как функции **GetColor** и **SetColor** подразумевают обращение к свойству **Color** у типа, который неизвестно какой во время компиляции, казалось бы, можно было бы поставить ограничение на обобщение, но, как я уже сказал, они не реализуют общего интерфейса и обобщить их просто так (без явного приведения) не получится. Видимо, придётся оставить как есть. Такие дела.

Comment: Да, общего у них к сожалению нет. Да `GetColor`/`SetColor` подразумевают `GetType` и `typeof`. Но никаких других путей сократить код кроме как подобная функция с <T> нет. Подобный код весьма читаем, тут бояться не за что.

Comment: @Yaroslav Добрый вечер, тут выше оставили решение, думаю, вам было бы интересно взглянуть.

Comment: Ну да, тоже сначала думал о интерфейсе, подумал что выйдет больше кода и забыл =) хотя так и правильнее. А в итоге SetColor/GetColor с приведением типов тоже не короткие, через switch и хочему-то не получается сделать.

Answer (score -2):

ну, в принципе, можна попробовать так 
способ крайне экзотический 
да и кода кажись больше вышло, аахахахахахахахахахха 
но всё же ) 
но лучше оставь своё, это тот случай когда повтор кода уместен

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;


class S
{
    delegate void VoidObjectColor(object o, Color c);
    delegate Color ColorObject(object o);
    delegate void VoidColorInt(Color c, int n);

    VoidColorInt dgFinished;
    VoidObjectColor dgColorChanged;
    ColorObject dgGetColor;

    List<TextMesh> texts;
    List<Image> images;
    List<SpriteRenderer> sprites;

    /// <summary>
    /// к этому обьекту присоединим сопрограммы
    /// </summary>
    MonoBehaviour behaviour;


    public static GameObject Paint(this GameObject obj, Color endColor, 
        int frames, float wait = float.NaN)
    {

        //
        // ну вот , вызываешь, все анимации затем выполнятся автоматически
        //
        TextAnimations(endColor, frames);

    }




    IEnumerator ChangeColorS(IEnumerator ie, Color targetColor, int fframes)
    {
        //
        // желательно
        // но не обязательно
        //
        if (ie == null) yield break;
        ie.Reset();
        //////

        Color color, deltaColor;

        while(ie.MoveNext())
        {
            color = dgGetColor(ie.Current);
            deltaColor = (targetColor - color) / fframes;

            for(int i = 0; i < fframes; i++)
            {
                color += deltaColor;
                dgColorChanged(ie.Current, color);
                yield return null;
            }
        }

        if(dgFinished != null) dgFinished(targetColor, fframes);
    }


    void TextAnimations(Color targetColor, int frames)
    {
        dgGetColor = (oobject) => ((TextMesh)oobject).color;
        dgColorChanged = (oobject, color) => ((TextMesh)oobject).color = color;
        dgFinished = ImageAnimations;
        behaviour.StartCoroutine(
            ChangeColorS(texts.GetEnumerator(), targetColor, frames));
    }
    void ImageAnimations(Color targetColor, int frames)
    {
        dgGetColor = (oobject) => ((Image)oobject).color;
        dgColorChanged = (oobject, color) => ((Image)oobject).color = color;
        dgFinished = SpriteAnimations;
        behaviour.StartCoroutine(
            ChangeColorS(images.GetEnumerator(), targetColor, frames));
    }
    void SpriteAnimations(Color targetColor, int frames)
    {
        dgGetColor = (oobject) => ((SpriteRenderer)oobject).color;
        dgColorChanged = (oobject, color) => ((SpriteRenderer)oobject).color = color;
        dgFinished = null;
        behaviour.StartCoroutine(
            ChangeColorS(sprites.GetEnumerator(), targetColor, frames));
    }

}
```